# Optimizing performance of GrabCut in opencv-java

Tags: java, algorithm, opencv

Recently I have been given a project, where I have to extract face (face+hair) from a given image.

I am solving this problem in the following ways.

1. I am extracting face locations from given image. [I am getting a rectangle]
2. I am extracting that rectangle and placing it in another image of same dimensions as input image.[face_image]
3. I am applying **grabCut** algorithm on the face_image of step 2.

When the face_image contains smooth background then the algorithm **grabCut** it working well but when the background of face_image is complex then the algorithm **grabCut** extracts some part of background too in the processed image.

Here is a snapshot of the results that I am getting.

[image: results of each step]

Here is my code of **grabCut**:

```
public void extractFace(Mat image, String fileNameWithCompletePath, 
                       int xOne, int xTwo, int yOne, int yTwo) throws CvException {

    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    Rect rectangle = new Rect(xOne, yOne, xTwo, yTwo);
    Mat result = new Mat();
    Mat bgdModel = new Mat();
    Mat fgdModel = new Mat();
    Mat source = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(3));
    Imgproc.grabCut(image, result, rectangle, bgdModel, fgdModel, 8, Imgproc.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT);
    Core.compare(result, source, result, Core.CMP_EQ);
    Mat foreground = new Mat(image.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(255, 255, 255));
    image.copyTo(foreground, result);
    Imgcodecs.imwrite(fileNameWithCompletePath, foreground);
}
```

**How can I improve performance of grabCut algorithm so that it will detect only face and hair from given image?**

Answer (score 11):

You should be able to do this by "helping" `grabCut` know a little about the foreground and background.  There is a [python tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html) that shows how this is done manually by selecting the foreground and background.

To do this automatically, you will need to find programmatic ways to detect the foreground and background.  The foreground consists mostly of hair and skin so you will need to detect them.

Skin - There are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561551/skin-detection-from-hue-saturation-histogram-opencv-python) papers and [blogs](https://razibdeb.wordpress.com/2013/09/10/skin-detection-in-c-using-opencv/) on how to do this.  Some of them are [pretty simple](http://spottrlabs.blogspot.com/2012/01/super-simple-skin-detector-in-opencv.html) and [this OpenCV tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/back_projection/back_projection.html) may also help.  I've found plain hue/saturation to get me pretty far.

Hair - This [is trickier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4832152/616644) but is [definitely](http://blog.gumgum.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Automated-Hair-Color-Determinationfinal.pdf) still [doable](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~yaser/pamis.pdf).  You may be able to hair and just use skin and background if this turns out to be too much work.

Background - You should be able to use [`range()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html) to find things in the image that are purple, green, and blue.  You know for sure that these things are not skin or hair and are therefore part of the background.

Use thresholding to create a mask of the areas that are most likely skin, hair, and background.  You can then use them as `bgdModel` and `fgdModel` (or the skin and hair masks) instead of `Mat()`.

Sorry this is so high-level.  I hope it helps!

Comment: I have tried many of these things, these things are not working as per my expectations.....

Comment: If you can be a little more detailed about what you tried and how it didn't work and add it to your question, maybe I can help a little more.

Comment: I am having different type of images, for some images the background is some much similar to hair that it is not possible for a program to differentiate between them, also the mentioned things are not working in all the cases....

Comment: While GrabCut is pretty good, it does have it limits.  You may need to perform your own optimizations after GrabCut has run.  Unfortunately, what you are doing is still an open research topic so it will be hard to find pre-made library calls that will do all the work for you.  You could also try finding/implementing another segmentation algorithm like TVSeg.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Another approach, since you have already detected the face, is to simply choose a better initial mask for initialising GrabCut - e.g. by using an oval instead of a rectangle.

1. Detect face rectangle (as you are already doing)
2. Create a mask:

   a) Create a new black image of the same size as your input image

   b) Draw a white-filled ellipse with the same height, width, top and left positions as the face rectangle
3. Call GrabCut with `GC_INIT_WITH_MASK` instead of `GC_INIT_WITH_RECT`:

   ```
   Imgproc.grabCut(image, mask, rectangle, bgdModel, fgdModel, 8, Imgproc.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK);
   ```

This initializes the foreground with a better model because faces are more oval-shaped than rectangle-shaped, so it should include less of the background to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to "play" with the rectangle coordinates `(int xOne, int xTwo, int yOne, int yTwo)`. Using your code and these coordinates 1, 400, 30, 400 I was able to avoid the background. *(I tried to post the images I successfully cropped but I need at least 10 reputation to do so)*

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Hi Ram, I am sorry if this was not the right place to post. 

Q: How can I improve performance of grabCut algorithm so that it will detect only face and hair from given image? 

My answer: The closer the rectagle is to the face the better the outcome will be.

Comment: I was reviewing your post and I selected the generic system message to displayed. It basically saying that this is more of a useful comment rather an answer as it not very detailed enough to be an answer and its asking you to post it as a comment. I know you can't post it as a comment as you don't have the reputation to do it.  Please answer some questions you know to gather the reputation and then try to comment or make your answer more detailed with examples and images as links I will convert the links to images by adding them for you.

Answer (score -7):

The best optimization that can be done to any Java routine is conversion to a native language.

Comment: The Java interface accesses the OpenCV library which is implemented in C++.  This is a "native" language and the library also heavily optimized.  Your assertion here is incorrect.